# Firestore: what's the purpose of the entries stored in the localStorage ("firestore_targets_firestore", etc)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We started having a lot of these errors lately in our app, all of them caused by this exceeded localStorage quota:

> @firebase/firestore:,
> Firestore (10.3.0): INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR: ,
> Error: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'firestore_mutations_firestore/[DEFAULT]/our-project-name/_309_zyHfGQsmRrVpOf2CjLYl4bnFTk42' exceeded the quota.

Because of that we now started monitoring the localStorage status of our users, and noticed some of them have literally hundreds of these entries stored in there ("firestore_clients_firestore", "firestore_targets_firestore", "firestore_zombie_firestore", etc.).

I assume they have something to do with the offline persistence. I would expect that they got cleaned up when not needed anymore, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

My question is: can these entries be manually deleted or would that cause problems? If it's the latter, is there a reliable way of finding out which entries are "stale" and safe to delete?